# How to run Scene Builder in eclipse mars 2?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, efxclipse

I want to work with javafx and Scene Builder in eclipse mars 2.
But there is no javafx item in eclipse menu. In file - new - others  there is no javafx item to create javafx program.
Then I try to install e(fx)clipse on eclipse and its done successfully but nothing add to my eclipse.
How can I run Scene Builder with eclipse (mars 2) ?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to download and install Scene Builder.
Here is the official link of oracle scene builder archive.

[Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html)

And if you've downloaded the e(fx)clipse, you don't need to enable it.
Just create a new project. Right Click on src -> New -> Other
Scroll down to JavaFX. Expand it. -> New FXML Document...
Right click on the fxml document and the second option is "Open with SceneBuilder".

Comment: [on src -> New -> Other ]  there is no JavaFX to expand.. it seems you dont read my post !

Comment: I have read your post already. I said, if you've downloaded "e(fx)clipse", then it should be there. Make sure you've downloaded e(fx)clipse.

Comment: i added e(fx)clipse from a zip file. which i find in here : https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1073003/

Answer (score 0):

I followed this

1. Installed `e(fx)clipse` from eclipse market place
2. Installed scene builder from
   `http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/#download`
3. Pointed the installed scene builder executable at
   `Eclipse>Preference>JavaFX>Scene Builder executable`

**Edited**

On successful installation of `e(fx)clipse` following items listed in installed software

```
  e(fx)clipse - IDE
  e(fx)clipse - IDE - Basic
  e(fx)clipse - IDE - Converter
  e(fx)clipse - IDE - CSS
  e(fx)clipse - IDE - DSL to setup JavaFX based code editors
  e(fx)clipse - IDE - FXGraph
  e(fx)clipse - IDE - FXML
  e(fx)clipse - IDE - GModel Feature
  e(fx)clipse - IDE - l10n support
  e(fx)clipse - IDE - PDE
  e(fx)clipse - IDE - RRobot
```

Comment: at Eclipse>Preference>  thre is no "Java FX" and i can not download e(fx)clipse from eclipse market beacuase they Boycott my country !

Comment: have you installed `e(fx)clipse`?

Answer (score 0):

finally i download eclipse neon and Installed e(fx)clipse from eclipse market place and javafx added to it . thanks for helping me

Comment: I'm using Mars, I don't see any issues while installing efxclipse plugin