# how to integrate javaFX scene builder kit in eclipse neon?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

I am new in JavaFX. I just want to integrate JavaFX scene builder kit in eclipse. I have downloaded the jar file from this link  [gluonhq.com](http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/#download). But I can't use this in Eclipse.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422052/how-to-run-scene-builder-in-eclipse-mars-2) gave steps how to use scene builder in eclipse but I want to use scene builder kit in eclipse.

I am currently using Eclipse Neon and installed e(fx)clipse-IDE from the eclipse marketplace.

Comment: Please check here,
https://stackoverflow.com/q/67646913/12539125