# How to integrate javaFX scene builder kit in Eclipse

Tags: scenebuilder

I found installation packages for **scene builder** on Gluonhq.com site. I tried install with deb version and it is working on my Ubuntu. There is **scene builder kit jar** version and I want to try to integrate to Eclipse. Can someone help me to know how to integrate javaFX **scene builder kit jar** in eclipse. I just want to know how to integrate to Eclipse.

Thanks in advance,

jj

Answer (score 0):

---

OK, I found it.

It is only to use for building new GUI application, such as application similar to Scene Builder. You don't have to write new code, just reuse code from Scene Builder. I am using Eclipse and following is how I add to User Libraries.

On Eclipse,
Window→Preference→Java→Build Path→User Libraries

New→User library name:→give some name, e.g. SceneBuilderKit

select on SceneBuilderKit you just created

Add External JARs→locate to SceneBuilderKit.jar and select it

Create a new java project

Right click on Project folder→Properties→Java Build Path
Libraries tab→Modulepath→Add Library…

Add Library…→User Library

Check SceneBuilderKit→Apply and close

Now you can use components from SceneBuilderKit

here is a video I found on YouTube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vq4s0kosyyo

jj

Comment: could you repost video link please ? or key words to find it , thanks

Comment: The YouTube link is dead but I still got video on google drive, please follow the link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qXZyi1QBPtXeH3qzC1DbpI_lCWTlFqzI/view?usp=sharing