# JavaFX Scene Builder executable file on mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, javafx

I have java fx scene builder on Mac and want to implement a file into Eclipse IDE. To do this, however, I need to find where the executable file is for the scene builder. I can see it in my applications and can open the contents of it but am not sure how to find where the executable file is.

Thanks in advance.

I did try researching this some say it's the .app and some say it's a dmg file but I can't find either..

Comment: A .dmg file is what you use to install something on macs. Most .apps are installed in /Applications but Finder does not show the `.app` part of the name. A .app is actually a folder with the executable inside - use Show Package Contents in Finder to see the contents.

Comment: Can you explain in detail what "want to implement a file into Eclipse IDE" means?  SceneBuilder can be run and used as a stand-alone application, it does not need to integrate with IDEs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

#### SceneBuilder Path

SceneBuilder is installed to the following path on OS X:

```
/Applications/SceneBuilder.app
```

#### SceneBuilder Stand-alone Usage

SceneBuilder can be run and used as a stand-alone application, it does not need to integrate with IDEs.

If I go to the location `/Applications` using Finder and click on the SceneBuilder icon, then SceneBuilder (Standalone) will run and I can use it to open and edit FXML files anywhere on my file system.  It can also be run by adding the SceneBuilder icon to the OS X dock and double-clicking it there.

#### Integration with IDEs

Some IDEs do have various degrees of optional integration with SceneBuilder.

##### IntelliJ Idea

In Idea, you can right-click an FXML file in the project and choose `Open In SceneBuilder` to open the file in SceneBuilder. In Idea, the [SceneBuilder path](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/opening-fxml-files-in-javafx-scene-builder.html) is configured via:

```
Settings > Language & Frameworks > JavaFX > Path to SceneBuilder
```

I didn't set the SceneBuilder path explicitly (if I recall, I could be wrong). The IDE probably picked up SceneBuilder from the default location, and set the value to:

```
/Applications/SceneBuilder.app
```

##### Eclipse

I'm not sure how to accomplish the same thing with Eclipse. There are [old Oracle tutorials that discuss it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/scene-builder-2/work-with-java-ides/sb-with-eclipse.htm), but I think they may be out of date.

There is a more recent StackOverflow question (though still over seven years old) that you could try:

- [How to run Scene Builder in eclipse mars 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38423470/1155209)

##### SceneBuilderKit

SceneBuilderKit is an embeddable version of SceneBuilder designed to run within an IDE. For example, when the kit is integrated with a given IDE, the IDE can provide a function to display a SceneBuilder editing pane inside the IDE itself rather than using the separate SceneBuilder application.  The IDE does this by using a SceneBuilderKit jar file installed by the IDE or an IDE plugin.  When that is done, there is no separate executable file or application for SceneBuilder.

In my experience, SceneBuilderKit is more buggy than the standalone SceneBuilder, but that might be fixed now as I have not used the kit in a long time. You can only use the kit if your IDE supports it (I don't know about support for SceneBuilderKit in Eclipse).

The standalone version of SceneBuilder always works regardless of IDE, and is what I use (aided by the convenience of the `Open In SceneBuilder` context menu in my IDE).

Comment: I am not an Eclipse user, so if somebody has more specific information for Eclipse, they can either edit this answer to provide the detail or add their own answer.